# Validate Dropzone js Using Parsley js

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, parsley.js

I have a multi-step form which has a dropzone js, I use Parsley js to validate each form step input fields so whenever the user clicks next button it validates the current block before going to the next step. But when it comes to the dropzone step i can't figure how to check if the user has uploaded an image or not before going to the next step. Is it even possible to do this using parsley js?

I just couldn't get it to work.